# MVC DataAnnotation Rendering Wrong HTMLin MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a straight forward model object that looks like this:

```
[DataMember]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime WeekEndingDate { get; set; }
```

And a View Page That Does this

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CashEntry.WeekEndingDate)
```

But My Problem is that it renders this as the markup:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The WeekEndingDate field is required." id="CashEntry_WeekEndingDate" name="CashEntry.WeekEndingDate" type="text" value="" />
```

When really data-val-required should be data-val-date . This is screwing up the validation also on the page of the date field. Any thoughts as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm affraid ASP.NET MVC 3 never creates data-val-date, here is list of attributes that might be created:

- data-val-number
- data-val-equalto
- data-val-range
- data-val-regex
- data-val-remote
- data-val-required
- data-val-length

You can create additional ModelValidatorProvider for DataType attribute like this:

```
public class ClientDataTypeNameModelValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (metadata == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("metadata");

        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        if (metadata.DataTypeName == "Date")
            yield return new DateModelValidator(metadata, context);
    }

    internal sealed class DateModelValidator : ModelValidator
    {
        public DateModelValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext)
            : base(metadata, controllerContext)
        { }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
            {
                ValidationType = "date",
                ErrorMessage = "[Put your error message here]"
            };

            return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { rule };
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
        {
            // No server-side validation logic
            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

And register it in your Global.asax like this:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ClientDataTypeNameModelValidatorProvider());
```

This should give you client validation support for DataType.Date, but you must remember that it will work only with jQuery validation as Microsoft validation doesn't have rule for date.